# ¿Como concatenar 2 inputs con Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hola buenas estoy tratando de concatenar 2 input distintos y mostrarla en un 3er input.

La idea de esto es rellenar en un 3er input que lo llamare resultado que extraera unos caractetres además de concadenar el nombre de usuario con el apellido, sin tener que actualizar la página.

Lo estoy tratando de hacer con JQUERY pero solo logro hacer que funcione para 1 input, y soy re novato en esto de jquery y javascript.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){

            var nombreUsuario="";
            var apellido = "";
            $('#nombre').keyup(function (){
                nombreUsuario = $('#nombre').val();
                //function concatenar(nombre,apellido);
                //$('#nombreUsuario').val(nombreUsuario); //FUNCIONA
            });

            $('#apellido_paterno').keyup(function (){
                apellido = $('#apellido_paterno').val();

                //function concatenar2(nombre,apellido);

            });

            $('#nombreUsuario').val(nombreUsuaerio+'.'+apellido);
        });

    </script>
```

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
 {!! Form::label('text', 'Nombre', ['class' => 'form-control-label']) !!}
 {!! Form::text('nombre',null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'nombre'])!!}
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
 {!! Form::label('text', 'Apellido Paterno', ['class' => 'form-control-label']) !!}
 {!! Form::text('apellido_paterno',null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
 {!! Form::label('text', 'Nombre de Usuario', ['class' => 'form-control-label']) !!}
 {!! Form::text('nombre_usuario',null, ['class' => 'form-control','readonly' => 'true','id'=>'nombreUsuario'])!!}
</div>
```

Comment: Lo que esta como contenido de los 2 inputs se coloque en un tercero?

Comment: En tu código no queda claro cuál es la acción que debe ocurrir para que el tercer input sea llenado con el nombre y el apellido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu código debería hacer algo así. Concatenar cada vez que escribes una letra en un input y así actualizar el último.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){

            var nombreUsuario="";
            var apellido = "";
            $('#nombre').keyup(function (){
                nombreUsuario = $('#nombre').val();
                //function concatenar(nombre,apellido);
                //$('#nombreUsuario').val(nombreUsuario); //FUNCIONA
              $('#nombreUsuario').val(nombreUsuaerio+'.'+apellido);

            });

            $('#apellido_paterno').keyup(function (){
                apellido = $('#apellido_paterno').val();

                //function concatenar2(nombre,apellido);
                $('#nombreUsuario').val(nombreUsuaerio+'.'+apellido);


            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: No se puede probar el snippet, faltan los inputs.

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que tenemos 3 inputs (firstname, lastname y name quien llevará el resultado de los 2 primeros inputs los cuales hemos identificado por su id)

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre">

<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Ingrese Apellido">

<input type="text" name="dui" id="dui" class="form-control">
```

luego en hacemos un script de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            var firstName="";
            var lastName ="";
            $('#firstname').keyup(function (){
                firstName = $('#firstname').val();
                $('#name').val(firstName+lastName);
            });

            $('#lastname').keyup(function (){
                lastName = $('#lastname').val();
                $('#name').val(firstName+' '+lastName);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Te debería funcionar de la siguiente manera, espero sea de utilidad, saludes y Bendiciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]